# Should I install python 3 in my virtualenv?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

I create virtualenv with this command `virtualenv blog`. But there is only python 2.7 in it. Let's say I want to code django in python3 , should I install python3? Because when I run `python manage.py shell` python2 promp appears. If I should, how can I do? In my real system both python 2 and 3 appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting with version 3.3, Python comes bundled with its own virtualenv. See the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/venv.html).

After installing Python 3, creating a virtual environment is as simple as:

```
/path/to/python3/python -m venv /path/for/new/environment #  or use pyvenv
```

You can then use it (i.e. `activate` and `deactivate`) the same way you did `virtualenv`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the --python option of the (old) virtualenv:

```
$ virtualenv my_virtualenv --python=python3  # Assume that the Python 3.x interpreter is available as python3 command
$ source my_virtualenv/bin/activate
(my_virtualenv)$ python --version  # Should return Python 3.x
```